# What does ->tm_mday for time mean?

Tags: c++, c, time

This is to save a filename as the current date. One of the lines of codes are as follows. I can't understand what the local->tm_mday means

The code is:

```
time_t my_time = time(NULL);
struct tm *local = localtime(&my_time);
 
day = local->tm_mday;            
month = local->tm_mon + 1;       
year = local->tm_year + 1900;
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm

Comment: `tm_mday` is day of the month, as mentioned earlier in comment

Comment: This question has already answers on a question about the difference between `.` and `->` ? lol ?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know what a struct member means, look at the documentation for that struct.

In this case that's [`tm`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm), from `<time.h>` (or `<ctime>` in C++)

Member objects

- `int tm_mday` day of the month – [1, 31]

That's different to

- `int tm_wday` days since Sunday – [0, 6]
- `int tm_yday` days since January 1 – [0, 365]